# Blur Lock Screen Wallpaper and Desktop Wallpaper are not same in Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: lock-screen, desktop-background

I've changed my desktop background but lock screen didn't change and remained same as old one. I even tried Change Lock Screen by tweaks but there was no difference. Any Solution?
I'm using Ubuntu 20.04

Comment: Did you restart your computer at least once after changing the desktop background?

Comment: yes i did. tried it several times.